# redirect all the routes to a page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have a number of routes like this

```
<Switch>
<Route path="/dashboard"   component={Dashboard}     key="dashboard" />
<Route path="/projects"    component={UserProjects}  key="userprojects" />
<Route path="/compute/servers" component={ProjectServerList}   key="projectserverlist" />
<Route path="/compute/snapshots"  component={ServerSnapshotList}  key="ServerSnapshotList" />
<Route path="/compute/keypairs"   component={KeypairList}         key="KeypairList" />
```

they work fine, but I want all of them to be redirected to '/dashboard' if a property is not set

I tried this :

```
{myproperty ?
<Switch>
<Route path="/dashboard"   component={Dashboard}     key="dashboard" />
</Switch>
:
<Switch>
<Route path="/dashboard"   component={Dashboard}     key="dashboard" />
<Route path="/projects"    component={UserProjects}  key="userprojects" />
<Route path="/compute/servers" component={ProjectServerList}   key="projectserverlist" />
<Route path="/compute/snapshots"  component={ServerSnapshotList}  key="ServerSnapshotList" />
<Route path="/compute/keypairs"   component={KeypairList}         key="KeypairList" />
  </Switch>
}
```

and failed misreablly

Im using
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
"react": "^16.13.1",

Comment: Probably I would try to use `useHistory` hook where you can use `history.push('/dashboard')` in the case when you don't have that property. With `<Switch>` and `<Route>` setup you are just configuring which route in the app should render which component, not really redirects based on condition. Maybe this repo helps to understand redirect options: https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples

Answer (score 1):

## Simple, clean & reusable-

Create a component which redirects to dashboard (or any path specified) if the property is not there, otherwise it renders the route itself.

```js
export const ProtectedRoute = ({comp: Component, redirectTo, path, key}) => {
  const propertyExists = "...";
  
  if (propertyExists) return <Route path={path} component={Component} key={key}></Route>;
  else return <Redirect to={redirectTo || "/dashboard"}/>
};
```

**Now inside routes**

```js
<Switch>
<Route path="/dashboard"   component={Dashboard}     key="dashboard" />
<ProtectedRoute path="/projects"    component={UserProjects}  key="userprojects" />
<ProtectedRoute path="/compute/servers" component={ProjectServerList}   key="projectserverlist" />
<ProtectedRoute path="/compute/snapshots"  component={ServerSnapshotList}  key="ServerSnapshotList" />
<ProtectedRoute path="/compute/keypairs"   component={KeypairList}         key="KeypairList" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little modification I hope it what you are looking for

```
 {myproperty ? (
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} key="dashboard" />
              <Route path="/projects" component={UserProjects} key="userprojects" />
              <Route path="/compute/servers" component={ProjectServerList} key="projectserverlist" />
              <Route path="/compute/snapshots" component={ServerSnapshotList} key="ServerSnapshotList" />
              <Route path="/compute/keypairs" component={KeypairList} key="KeypairList" />
            </Switch>
          ) : (
            <Route  component={Dashboard} key="dashboard" />
          )}
```

if "myproperty" has a value everything will goes normally , if not it will render component={Dashboard}